# Add DropShadowEffect to UIElement.Effect with x:Key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What I want to do is quite simple, but I cannot find how to do it.

I have a `DropShadowEffect` in a `ResourceDictionary` which has a key:

```
<DropShadowEffect x:Key="myDropShadow" BlurRadius="8" ShadowDepth="1.5" Direction="270" Color="Black" Opacity=".42" RenderingBias="Performance" />
```

And I'd like to add it to an Image Effect by referring to its key...

```
<Image>
    <Image.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect /> <!-- Here refer to myDropShadow -->
    </Image.Effect>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `StaticResource` markup extension for this:

```
<Image Effect="{StaticResource myDropShadow}" ... />
```